# A/B split testing in sitecore without DMS

Tags: testing, sitecore, sitecore7.2

I would like to ask you is it possible to create A/B split test for some component in Sitecore.NET 7.2 (rev. 151021) without using DMS. I heard that is possible to activate only A/B split testing funcionality or am I wrong ? But I have no idea how is it possible. Appreciate any help or advice.

Thanks

Krp0

Comment: A/B testing is all about statistics: did A perform better than B. Without DMS you are not collecting any analytics to be able to run compare the results. So the answer is no. You are able to run Personalisation without DMS though.

Answer (score 2):

No, A/B testing depends on Sitecore DMS. I don't think that is is possible to enable A/B testing without Sitecore DMS. (Or required a lot of customizations)

Comment: It is required. You wont even see the personalization button without Analytics turned on.

Comment: @dnstommy: That's true in Sitecore 8, but not other versions (original question is tagged Sitecore 7.2)

Comment: Is that true. I thought with 7.2, if you didn't have the Analytics config there and on, the button was missing. I thought I remember solving that for a client.